# TOP Data inconsistent Centos

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, top, cpu-usage

One Process Is showing that is it consuming 2000 percent cpu but in the Overall percentage in TOP command , it is showing only 2-3 percent .

Some other info : 1. There are total 32 cores in the system 2. System is running in virtualizd enviorment (VM) .

Here are the screenshoots :

[image]

[image]

In the above pics , All CPU's are idle , But one of the java process is consuming 2000% cpu .

Question :

Is the data correct or not ? and
If the data is correct then how we can understand the situiation .
If Data is not correct that what is the issue ?